# Regex Until But Not Including

Tags: regex, search, regex-lookarounds

For regex what is the syntax for search until but not including? Kinda like:

```
Haystack:
The quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog

Expression:
.*?quick -> and then everything until it hits the letter "z" but do not include z
```

Answer (score 208, accepted):

The explicit way of saying "search until `X` but not including `X`" is:

```
(?:(?!X).)*
```

where `X` can be any regular expression.

In your case, though, this might be overkill - here the easiest way would be

```
[^z]*
```

This will match anything except `z` and therefore stop right before the next `z`.

So `.*?quick[^z]*` will match `The quick fox jumps over the la`.

However, as soon as you have more than one simple letter to look out for, `(?:(?!X).)*` comes into play, for example

`(?:(?!lazy).)*` - match anything until the start of the word `lazy`.

This is using a **[lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**, more specifically a negative lookahead.

`.*?quick(?:(?!lazy).)*` will match `The quick fox jumps over the`.

**Explanation:**

```
(?:        # Match the following but do not capture it:
 (?!lazy)  # (first assert that it's not possible to match "lazy" here
 .         # then match any character
)*         # end of group, zero or more repetitions.
```

Furthermore, when searching for keywords, you might want to surround them with word boundary anchors: `\bfox\b` will only match the complete word `fox` but not the fox in `foxy`.

**Note**

If the text to be matched can also include linebreaks, you will need to set the "dot matches all" option of your regex engine. Usually, you can achieve that by prepending `(?s)` to the regex, but that doesn't work in all regex engines (notably JavaScript).

**Alternative solution:**

In many cases, you can also use a simpler, more readable solution that uses a lazy quantifier. By adding a `?` to the `*` quantifier, it will try to match as few characters as possible from the current position:

```
.*?(?=(?:X)|$)
```

will match any number of characters, stopping right before `X` (which can be any regex) or the end of the string (if `X` doesn't match). You may also need to set the "dot matches all" option for this to work. (Note: I added a non-capturing group around `X` in order to reliably isolate it from the alternation)

Comment: +1 Really nice answer, unfortunatly doesn't work with `grep`, but this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5979402/354831) does.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: Interesting. Why should the other one work and not this one? Both use lookahead assertions. Perhaps it's just because of the `(?:...)` non-capturing group? Does it work with `((?!X).)*`?

Comment: Really don't know, I'm not a regex expert nor grep. I was using `grep` to filter requests for only one database from mysql bin transformet in sql. Here is the beast : `grep -Po "(?s)use database_to_keep(.*?)(?=^use)" mysql-bin.000045.sql > filtered.sql`

Comment: Looks like a bash conflict since when I hit `Up` key, the last command is not the one I've used : `grep -Po "(?s)use database_to_keep(.*?)(?:(?!^use).)*" mysql-bin.000045.sql > filtered.sql`

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: `(?!^use)` doesn't do what you think. `^`  means "match the start of the string". You need to remove it. Also, the `(.*?)` part is completely pointless because it will never match anything but the empty string.

Comment: The context is that I want to filter from (start of line)use database_name(multiple lines)(start of line)use anoter_database_name. But yes you are right for the `(.*?)` part.

Comment: Good edit, @Tim, just add `$` alternative: replace `.*?(?=X)` with `.*?(?=X|$)`

Comment: Hi @TimPietzcker, thanks a lot for the help, I'm doing another regex using the pattern you gave: `(?:(?!X).)*` I need this in my case `(?:(?!R\$|\d).)*` match `R$` or a digit but don't put then on the result, but when I exec the regex it end up bringing both of then. This is the full regex I'm trying to exec in Js `/(?:(?!R$|\d).)* R?\$? ([0-9,.]+)/g`. Could you give me a help? After your pattern I need to match a currency.

Answer (score 20):

A [lookahead regex syntax](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookaround) can help you to achieve your goal. Thus a regex for your example is

```
.*?quick.*?(?=z)
```

And it's important to notice the `.*?` lazy matching before the `(?=z)` lookahead: the expression matches a substring until a **first** occurrence of the `z` letter.

Here is C# code sample:

```
const string text = "The quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dogz";

string lazy = new Regex(".*?quick.*?(?=z)").Match(text).Value;
Console.WriteLine(lazy); // The quick red fox jumped over the la

string greedy = new Regex(".*?quick.*(?=z)").Match(text).Value;
Console.WriteLine(greedy); // The quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(.*?quick.*?)z
```

Comment: This includes the "z" in the match, which is precisely what the asker wants to avoid. Perhaps the regex is intended to be a term in a '|' alternative, and that alternative regex is used to perform multiple matches. If the "z" is the beginning of a string that would be matched by **another** term in the alternative, then this match will be forfeited because the "z" is already consumed by the current match.