# Regex from character until end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey. First question here, probably extremely lame, but I totally suck in regular expressions :(

I want to extract the text from a series of strings that always have only alphabetic characters before and after a hyphen:

```
string = "some-text"
```

I need to generate separate strings that include the text before AND after the hyphen. So for the example above I would need `string1 = "some"` and `string2 = "text"`

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850074/regex-until-but-not-including) and it works for the text before the hyphen, now I only need the regex for the one after the hyphen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need regex for that, you can just split it instead.

```
var myString = "some-text";
var splitWords =  myString.split("-");
```

`splitWords[0]` would then be "some", and `splitWords[1]` will be "text".

If you actually have to use regex for whatever reason though - the `$` character marks the end of a string in regex, so `-(.*)$` is a regex that will match everything after the first hyphen it finds till the end of the string. That could actually be simplified that to just `-(.*)` too, as the `.*` will match till the end of the string anyway.

Comment: I need to match *from* the last instance of a character - this is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8374980/845584