# Separating a column based on regex

Tags: r, regex, string, tidyr

I have a column, named as "document" which has the following structure

```
1994_post_elections_Mandela.txt
1994_pre_elections_deKlerk.txt
1995_Mandela.txt
1996_Mandela.txt
1997_Mandela.txt
1998_Mandela.txt
1999_post_elections_Mandela.txt
1999_pre_elections_Mandela.txt
2000_Mbeki.txt
```

What I'd like to do is extract the president's name, which is always just before ".txt" and pop it into a new column - I don't mind about the other characters/numbers going into another column altogether. For various reasons that I won't explain here, I need to use the `separate` function from the `tidyr` package.

I tried to follow the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147639/how-to-separate-a-column-in-dplyr-based-on-regex) but my attempt failed miserably...

```
speech_gamma_exp<-speech_gamma %>%
separate(document, into=c("col1", "col2"), sep = "(\\_)(?!_*\\_)")
```

Comment: There is no function `separate` in `dplyr`

Comment: Question with `tidyr::separate` [Separate string after last underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49900323/separate-string-after-last-underscore)

Comment: Sorry, yes, I just automatically assumed it was from dplyr due to the >%> operator, but I have corrected myself.

Comment: I think you need `extract(document, into=c("col1", "col2"), "^(.*)_(.*)\\.txt$")`. With `separate`, you will always have the `.txt`s inside the strings.

Answer (score 1):

We cab use R base `gsub`:

```
> df1$President <- gsub(".*_(\\w+)\\.txt$", "\\1", df1$V1)
> df1
                               V1 President
1 1994_post_elections_Mandela.txt   Mandela
2  1994_pre_elections_deKlerk.txt   deKlerk
3                1995_Mandela.txt   Mandela
4                1996_Mandela.txt   Mandela
5                1997_Mandela.txt   Mandela
6                1998_Mandela.txt   Mandela
7 1999_post_elections_Mandela.txt   Mandela
8  1999_pre_elections_Mandela.txt   Mandela
9                  2000_Mbeki.txt     Mbeki
```

Assume your data.frame is:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="1994_post_elections_Mandela.txt
1994_pre_elections_deKlerk.txt
1995_Mandela.txt
1996_Mandela.txt
1997_Mandela.txt
1998_Mandela.txt
1999_post_elections_Mandela.txt
1999_pre_elections_Mandela.txt
2000_Mbeki.txt", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that you must use `separate`, here is a way. We can use `str_count` to get the maximum number of splits with `_` separator, and then make our `into` argument for `separate` based on that. Combined with `fill = "left"`, this means that we know the last split (the president.txt) will be in the last column. You can then remove `.txt` and the other columns as needed.

However, I think it is much simpler to just directly `mutate` the president name into a column with `str_extract`, as in the second example. This uses lookarounds to match letters preceded by `_` and followed by `.txt`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tibble(
  document = c(
    "1994_post_elections_Mandela.txt",
    "1994_pre_elections_deKlerk.txt",
    "1995_Mandela.txt",
    "1996_Mandela.txt",
    "1997_Mandela.txt",
    "1998_Mandela.txt",
    "1999_post_elections_Mandela.txt",
    "1999_pre_elections_Mandela.txt",
    "2000_Mbeki.txt"
  )
)

tbl %>%
  separate(
    col = document,
    into = str_c(
      "col",
      1:(as.integer(max(str_count(.$document, "_"))) + 1)
    ),
    sep = "_",
    fill = "left"
  )
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#>   col1  col2  col3      col4       
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>      
#> 1 1994  post  elections Mandela.txt
#> 2 1994  pre   elections deKlerk.txt
#> 3 <NA>  <NA>  1995      Mandela.txt
#> 4 <NA>  <NA>  1996      Mandela.txt
#> 5 <NA>  <NA>  1997      Mandela.txt
#> 6 <NA>  <NA>  1998      Mandela.txt
#> 7 1999  post  elections Mandela.txt
#> 8 1999  pre   elections Mandela.txt
#> 9 <NA>  <NA>  2000      Mbeki.txt

tbl %>%
  mutate(president = str_extract(document, "(?<=_)[:alpha:]*?(?=\\.txt)"))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   document                        president
#>   <chr>                           <chr>    
#> 1 1994_post_elections_Mandela.txt Mandela  
#> 2 1994_pre_elections_deKlerk.txt  deKlerk  
#> 3 1995_Mandela.txt                Mandela  
#> 4 1996_Mandela.txt                Mandela  
#> 5 1997_Mandela.txt                Mandela  
#> 6 1998_Mandela.txt                Mandela  
#> 7 1999_post_elections_Mandela.txt Mandela  
#> 8 1999_pre_elections_Mandela.txt  Mandela  
#> 9 2000_Mbeki.txt                  Mbeki
```

Created on 2018-09-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

This is quite straightforward using gsub or stringr/stringi. I could only come up with a tidyr::separate based solution after some jumping through hoops:

```
#### Create Data ####
pres_vector <- c("1994_post_elections_Mandela.txt", "1994_pre_elections_deKlerk.txt",
     "1995_Mandela.txt", "1996_Mandela.txt", "1997_Mandela.txt", "1998_Mandela.txt",
     "1999_post_elections_Mandela.txt", "1999_pre_elections_Mandela.txt", "2000_Mbeki.txt")

#### Libraries ####
library(stringi)
library(tidyr)

#### Solution ####    
pres_vector %>% stri_reverse %>% data.frame(x = .) %>% 
    separate(x, c("file_ext", "pres")) %>% { .[["pres"]] } %>% stri_reverse -> pres_names

print(pres_names)
[1] "Mandela" "deKlerk" "Mandela" "Mandela" "Mandela" "Mandela" "Mandela" "Mandela" "Mbeki"
```

This works because of the pattern of the strings. Separate will split on alphanumeric characters by default. The last part of the string is the file extension, and the 2nd last part of the string is the President's name.

Thus, reversing the string puts the (reversed) file extension first and (reversed) President's name second. Separate allows us to extract these first 2 parts and subset to keep only the President's name. And finally, reversing this substring (the President's reversed name) gives us the President's name (without reversal).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use **stringr** for this kind of tasks (`gsub` is fine too)

```
library(stringr)
pattern <- ".*_(\\w+)\\.txt$"    
data$president <- str_extract(data$document, "(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\\.txt)")
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0T9QVL/1)