# Have to extract the start of word by stripping the last occurrence of symbol ^ characters to end by regex extract

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I want to use the regex_replace or regexp_extract in hive where i can get only the first **n** occurrences of special character **"^"** except the last occurrence and text after last occurrence.
f
For example:

- `101^11` should extract `101`
- `101^1111^232` should extract `101^1111`
- `144^899^890^1` should extract `1144^899^890`

I have to do with only regex and not with string functions or udf.

Comment: Wouldn't this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374742/regex-last-occurrence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with 
**regexp_extract** function

**In hive:**

```
hive> select regexp_extract('101^11',"(.*)\\^",1)
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 101  |
+------+--+
```

**In Scala:**

```
scala> val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
scala> val df= hiveContext.sql("""select regexp_extract('101^11','(.*)\\\^',1)""");
scala> df.show()
+---+
|_c0|
+---+
|101|
+---+
```

**In Pyspark:**

```
>>> hiveContext=HiveContext(sc)
>>> df=hiveContext.sql("select regexp_extract('101^11','(.*)\\\^',1)")
>>> df.show()
+---+
|_c0|
+---+
|101|
+---+
```

Comment: I have tried this example and it was success.Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: If i try the same query with spark sql the data is not being returned for extract column. DataFrame df=     hiveContext.sql("select regexp_extract(eid,'(.*)\\^',1) as eid1,name from employee");

System.out.println("schema "+df.schema());
System.out.println("first record"+df.first());     first record[,rakes]

Comment: Please enclose with triple quotes ***val df= hiveContext.sql("""select regexp_extract('101^11','(.*)\\^',1)""");*** it should work..!!

Comment: I am trying in spark sql java, it is showing error with triple quotes in eclipse.