# VBScript function to remove trailing comma from json string

Tags: vbscript

I have the following string and want to remove the trailing comma.  How can I accomplish this in VB script.  I thought my replace should do it.

I have: `str = [{"key" : "132904", }]`

I want: `[{"key" : "132904"}]`

I'm doing: `str = Replace(str, ", }]", "}]")` but nothing is happening cause my string remains the same.

Comment: `str = Replace(str, ", ", "")`

Comment: You can do it with a sample Regex [Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/yharsv/1)

Comment: Could use a [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8374742/692942) to only remove the last `(?:.(?!,))+$`.

Comment: Every other suggested solution assumes you will only ever have the one key value pair in the JSON object, anything else will break.

Answer (score 0):

The `Replace` statement is just fine for the mentioned purpose.

If I execute this code:

```
dim str
str = "[{""key"" : ""132904"", }]"
msgbox "original: " & vbNewLine & str
str = Replace(str, ", }]", "}]")
msgbox "After update: " & vbNewLine & str
```

I get

[image]

and then

[image]

The trailing "," is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

`Replace` statement and `RegX.Replace` works just fine for me.

```
dim str,RegX, SearchPattern, ReplacedText
Set RegX = NEW RegExp

str = "[{""key"" : ""132904"", }]"

' Use Regular expression
SearchPattern = ",.*}"
ReplaceString = "}"
RegX.Pattern = SearchPattern
RegX.Global = True
ReplacedText = RegX.Replace(str, ReplaceString)

msgbox "str: " & str & vbNewLine & _
       "Using Replace: " & Replace(str, ", }]", "}]")& vbNewLine & _
       "Using Regex: " & ReplacedText
```

[image]