# Regex Last Character or Position from Found String

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I've looked through [Regex Last occurrence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374742/regex-last-occurrence) but cannot get the regex to work for my example string ("https://www.fakesite.com test one").  I need to return the last character of the website name only (or the position).  I have the expressions for both capturing the site and obtaining the last character but cannot get the expression to get the right look behind.

```
(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s] 
{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.| 
(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}) <- Regular Expression for website

(?=.?$).   <-  Regular Expression for retrieving last character
```

I've been using https://regex101.com/ to try and find, but no luck.

**How can I retrieve the last character or position?**

[image: LastCharacterImage]

**--Edit--**

**How can I retrieve just the last character of any string?** (I need just the letter 'r' in System Engineer).  'System Engineer' is dynamic.

"for the position of System Engineer located in"

```
(?<=position of )(.*)(?= located)   <- regex to capture System Engineer between words 'position of' and 'located'
```

Comment: the big regex hasd probleems. the last char regexr is `[\S\s]$`

Comment: Yes, but if I didn't know the string and need to capture that first how can I achieve that (I didn't know the text would be 'System Engineer')

Comment: You need to know something about the String or pattern, because that's the way regular expressions work behind the scene. I can give you a work around in the programming language though. Let's say you get some dynamic string as input like **System Engineer** for example; then what you can do is you can create the regex dynamically. Something like `String str = "SomeString"; String regex = "(?<=" + str + ")\w;`

Comment: Yes, I know the text will be between the words "position of" and "located"

Comment: Please check [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/oTA5eS/2). Group 1 does it for you. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, that will work, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the below regex. The below regex will check for valid url address as well as will get you the last character of your url.

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}(\w)\b(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}`** - Matches the `http/https://` part of the regex along with `www` and the domain name before the first `.`.
>
> **`[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}`** - This part matches the last of the url part.
>
> **`(\w)`** - Represents a capturing group capturing the last character of the url. You may use `([a-zA-Z0-9])` manually if you don't want to include `_`.
>
> **`\b(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)`** - Matches the rest part of the url like `.uk` or `.in`, etc. zero or more times.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/vjNu4U/9)

**Reference: The regex for matching the valid url is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/7571182) answer.**

If you want to get amendments in your regex; just add `[a-zA-Z]` after your regex. You can find the demo [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/xqKLY7/3)

Comment: Can you help with the edit I made, I need help making this generalized, I read through the Explanation but could not get the last character of the string and capture the second group.