# strsplit it by the last "number_"

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, strsplit

Hello I have a df such as

```
COL1
SEQ_1.1_0
SEQ2.2_2
AB_1_2.3_3
ACC.3_3
```

and I would like to strsplit it by the last "number_"

and get :

```
COL1      COL2
SEQ_1.1   0
SEQ2.2    2
AB_1_2.3  3
ACC.3     3
```

so far I tried:

```
strsplit(df$COL1, "*.[0-9]_")
```

here is the code I use and need to use

```
df$shorti = do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df$COL1), "*.[0-9]_"))[,1]
```

Comment: I added why I use strsplit ate the end of the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyr::extract` :

```
tidyr::extract(df, COL1, c('COL1', 'COL2'), regex = '(.*)_(.*)', convert = TRUE)

#      COL1 COL2
#1  SEQ_1.1    0
#2   SEQ2.2    2
#3 AB_1_2.3    3
#4    ACC.3    3
```

With `strsplit`  using regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16848676) with negative lookahead.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(df$COL1, '(_)(?!.*_)', perl = TRUE))
```

Comment: do you have a strsplit solution ? I mean I need only the regex part

Comment: @chippycentra Added `strsplit` solution.

Comment: Ronak, could you explain the tidyr code, there are more than 1 underscores _, how it takes the last one to split?

Comment: @KarthikS regex by definition are greedy so if there are multiple occurrence of a character it always matches the last one unless you make them non-greedy with `?`. (`(.*?)`)

Answer (score 2):

Using substr:

```
> dat                  
        COL1
1  SEQ_1.1_0
2   SEQ2.2_2
3 AB_1_2.3_3
4    ACC.3_3
> dat$COl2 <- substr(dat$COL1,nchar(dat$COL1),nchar(dat$COL1)+1)
> dat$COL1 <- substr(dat$COL1,1,nchar(dat$COL1)-2)
> dat
      COL1 COl2
1  SEQ_1.1    0
2   SEQ2.2    2
3 AB_1_2.3    3
4    ACC.3    3
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `base R`solution with `sub`:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  COL1 = c("SEQ_1.1_0",
  "SEQ2.2_2",
  "AB_1_2.3_3",
  "ACC.3_3")
)
```

Solution:

```
df$COL2 <- sub(".*(\\d$)", "\\1", df$COL1) 
df$COL1 <- sub("_\\d$", "", df$COL1)
```

Result:

```
df
      COL1 COL2
1  SEQ_1.1    0
2   SEQ2.2    2
3 AB_1_2.3    3
4    ACC.3    3
```