# Getting the last occurrence of a match that is inside parenthesis using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to use regular expressions to get the text inside parenthesis in a sentence. But if the string has two or more occurrence, the pattern I am using gets everything in between. I google it and some sources tells me to use negative lookahead and backreference, but it is not working as expected. The examples I found are: [Here](https://www.regextester.com/102418), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374742/regex-last-occurrence)

An example of a string is:

`s = "Para atuar no (GCA) do (CNPEM)"`

What I want is to get just the last occurrence: `"(CNPEM)"`

The pattern I am using is:

`pattern = "(\(.*\))(?!.*\1)"`

But when I run (using python's re module) I get this:

`output = (GCA) do (CNPEM)`

How can I get just the last occurrence in this case?

Comment: Use `pattern = r'.*(\([^)]*\))'`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.findall` here, and then access the last match:

```py
s = "Para atuar no (GCA) do (CNPEM)"
last = re.findall(r'\(.*?\)', s)[-1]
print(last)  # (CNPEM)
```