# Regex to mimic the js split function and extract the text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text where I need to extract the community name
The delimiter for spliting is " - "

Hence `Iowa - Cedar Rapids - Meth-Wick Community`
must give result as `Meth-Wick Community`

if input is `Iowa - Cedar Rapids - The Gardens of Cedar Rapids`
result must be `The Gardens of Cedar Rapids`

I have tried with

```
"Iowa - Cedar Rapids - The Gardens of Cedar Rapids".match(new RegExp(/([A-Z])\w{3}/gi))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one out for size:

```js
console.log("Iowa - Cedar Rapids - The Gardens of Cedar Rapids".replace(/([\w\s]+)\s-\s([\w\s]+)\s-\s([\w\s]+)/i,'$3'));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can do a negative lookahead to find the last occurrence of the delimiter as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8374980/5417843
and then extract the community name from it.

```
input = "Iowa - Cedar Rapids - The Gardens of Cedar Rapids"
communityName = input.match(new RegExp('- (?:.(?!- ))+$')) // '- The Gardens of Cedar Rapids'
communityName[0].substring(2) // 'The Gardens of Cedar Rapids'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution, used less regex as much as possible:

```
"Iowa - Cedar Rapids - Meth-Wick Community".split(/ - /g).slice(-1)[0]
"Iowa - Cedar Rapids - The Gardens of Cedar Rapids".split(/ - /g).slice(-1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
const string = "Iowa - Cedar Rapids - The Gardens of Cedar Rapids"
console.log((string.match(/.*\s+-\s+(.+)/) || [''])[1])
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/ft0iMY/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```