# Regex to capture everything before first optional string

Tags: php, regex

I want to capture a pattern upto but not including the first instance of an optional other pattern with preg_match, eg:

```
ABCDEFGwTW$%                         | capture ABCD
@Q%HG@H%hg afdgwsa g   weg#D DEFG    | capture @Q%HG@H%hg afdgwsa g   weg#D D
@Q%HDEFG@H%hg afdgwsa g   weg#D DEFG | capture @Q%HD
```

So in the above case anything before the first instance of the string `EFG` is captured. also, if the `EFG` string is not present then I want to capture the whole string.

I would have thought that the following would work, but no such luck:

```
$pattern = '/(.*)(?:EFG)?/';
preg_match($pattern, 'Q$TQ@#%GEFGw35hqb', $matches);
print_r($matches);
//should give: 'Q$TQ@#%G'
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use

```
'/(.*?)(?=EFG|$)/'
```

Comment: ah very nice - i didnt think of matching EFG or the end of the line :)

Comment: bro, you're my hero

Answer (score 5):

Try this: `(.*?)(?:EFG|$)`

This will match any character (as few as possible) until it finds EFG.

Comment: the problem is that it will not match a string which does not contain EFG

Comment: Right, oops! Match the end of line character, too. (Updated answer.)

Comment: sorry @Josh M., @Jens beat you to it :P

Comment: That's okay, my fault for missing that requirement.

Comment: As a note, even the updated version is not correct: it actually includes the optional string in the result (whereas the question was 'capture everything before first optional string')

Comment: Well, it matches stuff including the optional string, but the important part is fetched from the first capture group e.g. `RegExp.exec(/(.*?)(?:EFG|$)/, 'Q$TQ@#%GEFGw35hqb')[1]` to get only "Q$TQ@#%G".

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
$str = 'Q$TQ@#%GEFGw35hqb';
$res = preg_split('/EFG/', $str);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: or better still `list($match) = preg_split('/EFG/', $haystack)` to capture the string straight into a vairable :)

Comment: Using a `preg_` call with a literal pattern is needless overhead.  Why not just `explode()` with `EFG`?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the result with a lot less confusion:

Just check a simpler version of the pattern to match, and if not, use the original string:

```
<?php
$match = 'Q$TQ@#%GEFGw35hqb';
if (preg_match('/^(.*)EFG/', $match, $matches)) {
    $match = $matches[1];
}

echo $match;
```

Comment: yeah i could have done a similar thing with `stripos` too but i thought i'd learn a bit about regex - its neater imo

Comment: Yeah ;) though, if performance is an issue, you should use `strpos` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_match()` with a pattern that uses lazy matching and a lookahead is going to take more steps than just using `preg_replace()` with greedy matching (and no lookarounds) and simply replacing the optional match with an empty string.  If the needle doesn't exist, then nothing is changed in the string.  Super easy.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/j2YZP))

```
$strings = [
    'ABCDEFGwTW$%',
    '@Q%HG@H%hg afdgwsa g   weg#D DEFG',
    '@Q%HDEFG@H%hg afdgwsa g   weg#D DEFG',
    'No needle in the haystack',
];

var_export(preg_replace('/EFG.*/', '', $strings));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'ABCD',
  1 => '@Q%HG@H%hg afdgwsa g   weg#D D',
  2 => '@Q%HD',
  3 => 'No needle in the haystack',
)
```