# JavaScript RegEx Match Failing

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having issues matching a string using regex in javascript. I am trying to get everything up to the word "at". I am using the following and while it doesn't return any errors, it also doesn't do anything either.

```
var str = "Team A at Team B";
var matches = str.match(/(.*?)(?=at|$)/);
```

I tried multiple regex patterns before coming across this SO post, [Regex to capture everything before first optional string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979342/regex-to-capture-everything-before-first-optional-string), but it doesn't to return what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `?` at your first capturing group, and `|$` from your second, and add `^` to mark beginning of string:

```
str.match(/^(.*)(?=at)/)
```

Alternatively (I personally find below easier to read, but your call):

```
str.substr(0, str.search(/\bat\b/))
```