# Regex to match user and user@domain

Tags: java, regex

A user can login as "user" or as "user@domain". I only want to extract "user" in both cases. I am looking for a matcher expression to fit it, but im struggling.

```
final Pattern userIdPattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)[@]{0,1}.*");
final Matcher fieldMatcher = userIdPattern.matcher("user@test");
final String userId = fieldMatcher.group(1)
```

userId returns "user@test". I tried various expressions but it seems that nothing fits my requirement :-(

Any ideas?

Comment: You must have `if (fieldMatcher.find())` there, too, right? Try `String userId = s.replaceFirst("^([^@]+).*", "$1");`

Comment: `(.*)@?.*` maybe?

Comment: `yourString.split("@")[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `"(.*)[@]{0,1}.*"` pattern with `.matches()`, the `(.*)` grabs the whole line first, then, when the regex index is still at the end of the line, the `[@]{0,1}` pattern triggers and matches at the end of the line because it can match 0 `@` chars, and then `.*` again matches at that very location as it matches any 0+ chars. Thus, the whole line lands in your Group 1.

You may use

```
String userId = s.replaceFirst("^([^@]+).*", "$1");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gTQOgC/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([^@]+)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): any 1+ chars other than `@`
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question. An admin is allowed to edit matching patterns to his needs. So i will use this:
    `final Pattern userIdPattern = Pattern.compile("([^@]+)[@]{0,1}.*");`

Comment: @Henfo `[@]{0,1}` is redundant, it makes no difference if there is `[@]{0,1}` inside the pattern or not.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of googling came up with this:

```
(.*?)(?=@|$)
```

Will match everthing before an optional @

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979342/regex-to-capture-everything-before-first-optional-string for where I got this

Comment: Depending on the Java code where this pattern is used, it might not work what is expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm intrigued... why won't it?

Comment: If you use it with `.matches()`, Group 1 for `user@domain.com` string will be the whole string. You borrowed the pattern from PHP related question, and in PHP, the `preg_match` function returns partial matches.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping it simple and not relying on regex in this case if you are using java and have a simple case like you provided.

You could simply do something like this:

```
String userId = "user@test";

if (userId.indexOf("@") != -1)
    userId = userId.substring(0, userId.indexOf("@"));

// from here on userId will be "user".
```

This will always either strip out the "@test" or just skip stripping it out when it is not there.

Using regex in most cases makes the code less maintainable by another dev in the future because most devs are not very good with regular expressions, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

You included the `@` as optional, so the match tries to get the longest user name.  As you didn't put the restriction of a username is not allowed to have `@`s in it, it matched the longest string.

Just use:

```
[^@]*
```

as the matching subexpr for usernames (and use `$0` to get the matched string)

Or you can use [this one](https://regex101.com/r/eDCRvK/1) that can be used to find several matches (and to get both the user part and the domain part):

```
\b([^@\s]*)(@[^@\s]*)?\b
```

The `\b` force your string to be tied to word boundaries, then the first group matches non-space and non-`@` chars (any number, better to use `+` instead of `*` there, as usernames must have at least one char) followed (optionally) by a `@` and another string of non-space and non-`@` chars).  In this case, `$0` matches the whole email addres, `$1` matches the username part, and `$2` the  `@domain` part (you can refine to only the domain part, adding a new pair of parenthesis, as in

```
b([^@\s]*)(@([^@\s]*))?\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eDCRvK/2).