# Regex -> Replace up to but not including

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Im trying to replace this `@Model.<A Word>` to `$Model.<A Word>$`

so, `@Model.Test` would become `$Model.Test$`

While searching SO, i found this thread

[Regex Until But Not Including](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850074/regex-until-but-not-including)

Which the answer worked.. until I had to replace one in this sentence

```
Élément @Model.Title a besoin d'être\napprouvé
```

Modifying the answer slightly to : `@Model\.((?:(?![ ]).)*)`

Results with

```
Élément $Model.Title a$ besoin d'être\napprouvé
```

I want the $ to be just after Title -> `$Model.Title$`

Any help would be appreciated - I'm quite new to regex.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/o4bb9rz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
@Model\.(\w+)
```

This will match `@Model.` followed by one or more '[word characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter)'. For example:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(
    "Élément @Model.Title a besoin d'être\napprouvé", 
    @"@Model\.(\w+)", 
    "$$Model.$1$$"); // Élément $Model.Title$ a besoin d'être\napprouvé
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you definitely don't need look-arounds. Since you are just going to match words after `@Model.`, you can just replace the following regex:

```
"@(Model[.]\w+)"
```

with:

```
"$$$1$$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `@Model\.(\S+)` with a replacement string `$Model.$1$`

Comment: I ended up with p.s.w.g's answer but i tried this anyway (just for reference).

Élément @Model.Title a besoin d'être\napprouvé still -> still ends up with $Model.Title a$

Comment: @AlanCiantar Are you sure, i just have re-tested that and it was correct.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/swMjwN3.png   -- I'm using this site (http://myregexp.com/signedJar.html) -> maybe its old?

Comment: @AlanCiantar Perhaps it is old, nevertheless your problem is solved so it is OK.

Comment: @AlanCiantar The difference between this answer and mine (and Rohit's) is that this will match any non-whitespace characters while mine (and Rohit's) will match any word characters. E.g. this will replace `@Model.Title-Text` with `$Model.Title-Text$` while mine will replace `@Model.Title-Text` with `$Model.Title$-Text`. Both are good approaches, depending on exactly what you need.

Comment: @p.s.w.g + Rohit Thank you both :) Apparently Rohit's answer works on other online regex testers O.o - again, ty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Perl/JavaScript regex format):

```
s/@(Model\.[^ ]+)/\$$1\$/g
```

*Update:*

And of course our friend `sed`:

```
sed 's/@\(Model\.[^ ]\+\)/$\1$/g'
```

*Update 2:*

Removed spaces.

Comment: The question is tagged C#. Why would you post Perl? Also, this won't work if the word being matched is not immediately followed by a space. e.g. `This is my @Model.Title!`.

Comment: Fair comment.  But the question seems to be more related to RegExes than it does C# specifics, so I felt providing something to an unanswered (at the time) question, is better than leaving it unanswered.